# How to create an array of bits and turn them into a bitmap VB?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, bitmap

I want to create an array of bits and turn them into a bitmap in vb? I know how to create a bitmap like this `Dim NBitmap as new bitmap(width,height)`, Then edit its pixels like this `NBitmap.setpixel(x,y,color)`. This is slow however I thought that creating an array or something then converting it to a bitmap would be faster. But i don't know how... Any help would be nice!
Example:

```
Dim SM = DateTime.Now.Millisecond
Dim Texture As Bitmap = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Noah\Desktop\graphics\Grass.jpg")
Dim w = 600
Dim h = 600
Dim Pixels(600, 600) As Color
Dim x = 0
Do Until x = 600
    Dim y = 0
    Do Until y = 600
        Pixels(x, y) = Texture.GetPixel(x, y)
        y += 1
    Loop
    x += 1
Loop
Dim EM = DateTime.Now.Millisecond
Dim FM = EM - SM
If FM < 0 Then
    FM += 1000
End If
Dim FPS = 1000 / FM
Dim ETDFrame As New Bitmap(600, 600)
ETDFrame.image = Pixels().convertBMP
```

I know that this code dosen't work but if gives an example if what i want.My goal is to create a new bitmap and edit all the pixels super fast, fast enough for a 3d game...

Comment: What you are creating with that code is not an array of bits, but an array of Color structures (each structure presumably consists of four bytes). I doubt that you will see any improvement in speed by trying to code your own equivalent of `SetPixel`. And you are adding the time it takes to convert from and to your array.

Comment: I added an additional sentence to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to do.  It appears as if you are trying to convert a .jpg to a .bmp.  If that is so, you can just call the `.Save` method of the Image class:

```
'Load the bitmap
Dim bm As Bitmap = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Noah\Desktop\graphics\Grass.jpg")
'Save as .bmp
bm.Save("C:\Users\Noah\Desktop\graphics\Grass.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
```

If you really need to work with the pixels, then using `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` will be too slow.  You need to use `LockBits` to work directly with the bitmap data.  Something like this:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Private Sub DoGraphics()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer

    'PixelSize is 3 bytes for a 24bpp Argb image.
    'Change this value appropriately
    Dim PixelSize As Integer = 3

    'Load the bitmap
    Dim bm As Bitmap = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Noah\Desktop\graphics\Grass.jpg")

    'lock the entire bitmap for editing
    'You can change the rectangle to specify different parts of the image if needed.
    Dim bmData As BitmapData = bm.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bm.PixelFormat)

    'Declare empty Color array
    Dim pixels(bm.Width - 1, bm.Height - 1) As Color

    'loop through the locked area of the bitmap.
    For x = 0 To bmData.Width - 1
        For y = 0 To bmData.Height - 1
            'Get the various color offset locations for each pixel.
            'This calculation is for a 24bpp rgb bitmap
            Dim blueOfs As Integer = (bmData.Stride * x) + (PixelSize * y)
            Dim greenOfs As Integer = blueOfs + 1
            Dim redOfs As Integer = greenOfs + 1

            'Read the value for each color component for each pixel
            Dim red As Integer = Marshal.ReadByte(bmData.Scan0, redOfs)
            Dim green As Integer = Marshal.ReadByte(bmData.Scan0, greenOfs)
            Dim blue As Integer = Marshal.ReadByte(bmData.Scan0, blueOfs)

            'Create a Color structure from each color component of the pixel
            'and store it in the array
            pixels(x, y) = Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue)
        Next
    Next

    'Do something to the pixels array here:
    For x = 0 To bmData.Width - 1
        For y = 0 To bmData.Height - 1
            pixels(x, y) = Color.Red
        Next
    Next

    'Update the bitmap from the pixels array
    For x = 0 To bmData.Width - 1
        For y = 0 To bmData.Height - 1
            'Get the various color offset locations for each pixel.
            'This calculation is for a 24bpp rgb bitmap
            Dim blueOfs As Integer = (bmData.Stride * x) + (PixelSize * y)
            Dim greenOfs As Integer = blueOfs + 1
            Dim redOfs As Integer = greenOfs + 1

            'Set each component of the pixel
            'There are 3 bytes that make up each pixel (24bpp rgb)
            Marshal.WriteByte(bmData.Scan0, blueOfs, pixels(x, y).B)
            Marshal.WriteByte(bmData.Scan0, greenOfs, pixels(x,y).G)
            Marshal.WriteByte(bmData.Scan0, redOfs, pixels(x,y).R)

        Next
    Next

    'Important!
    bm.UnlockBits(bmData)

    'Save the updated bitmap
    bm.Save("C:\Users\Noah\Desktop\graphics\Grass.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)

End Sub
```

I hope this helps.

**UPDATE:** I have updated the code to show changing the pixel values.

Comment: I made another loop for x = 0 to bm.width with an embedded loop for y = 0 to bm.height. and inside the y loop i typed in pixels(x,y) = color.red, But then when i display the bitmap it looks the same as it did before?

Comment: I did a message box of pixels(0,0).tostring and i says color[red]?

Comment: Does changing values of pixels(x,y) not change the actual pixel for the bitmap?If not can i do it with the code you provided besides setpixel?

Comment: Thats super fast also?

Comment: Changing a value in the pixels array will not affect the original bitmap.  If you wish to change the bitmap, you must use `Marshal.WriteByte`.  I've updated my answer to show this.  And this is about as fast as you can get with VB.Net.  It is very much faster than using GetPixel and SetPixel.

Comment: Note:  Be sure to change the LockBits mode to `ReadWrite` instead of `ReadOnly`

Comment: I found a way that changed every pixel at 280 fps, but this post was helpful. :D

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a property of the `Bitmap` class that returns an array/list of all the pixel colors, so you can't set them all at once.[The Microsoft documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) actually provides example code getting and setting pixel colors in two nested loops, much like you're already doing.

If your end goal is to store the pixel information to pass to another `Bitmap`, I would suggest [the Clone method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.clone(v=vs.110).aspx). Rather than expend the time and effort of extracting the data into your own format, just use the one that's already provided. The predefined methods are almost always the most efficient, so this should be your best bet for performance.

If you truly *must* store the colors in an array, then you'll have to write a method to loop through every color and use `SetPixel` one pixel at a time. This sounds like exactly what you're doing now though, so this won't save any time.